# How can I check the transaction logs in `anchor test`?

Tags: anchor, local-cluster

If my Anchor instruction handler has some log messages:

```
msg!("The number is: {}, the color is: {}", number, color);
```

I know I can check the Solana logs either using `solana logs`:

```
Transaction executed in slot 365:
  Signature: 64bbNn8Ld8javFdpQ9hQpS2NmRaH7weCePfAWcn2ZHxoR9Wv5rXE5CmN9x3XDS7U2EfJ2Tvzv46wLGBpLE35gLuy
  Status: Ok
  Log Messages:
    Program 8Mb5fA43uBMLVyxWZewvvVNGbvmPu5hLLfVxGyDN1jTE invoke [1]
    Program log: Instruction: SetFavorites
    Program log: The number is: 23, the color is: red
    Program 8Mb5fA43uBMLVyxWZewvvVNGbvmPu5hLLfVxGyDN1jTE consumed 1194 of 200000 compute units
    Program 8Mb5fA43uBMLVyxWZewvvVNGbvmPu5hLLfVxGyDN1jTE success
```

or https://explorer.solana.com/ connected to localhost

[image]

But how can I assert the transaction log included a particular message in my unit tests?

Eg, (pseudo-code follows):

```
it("Sets our favorites", async () => {
  const favoriteNumber = new anchor.BN(23);
  const tx = await program.methods.setFavorites(favoriteNumber, "red").rpc();
  const logs = getLogs(tx);
  assert(logs.includes("The number is: 23, the color is: red"));  
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirm the transaction, then use [`getTransaction()`](https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction) to check the logs:

```
it("Sets our favorites", async () => {
  const favoriteNumber = new anchor.BN(23);
  const tx = await program.methods.setFavorites(favoriteNumber, "red").rpc();
  const connection = program.provider.connection;

  const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
  await connection.confirmTransaction(
    {
      blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
      lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
      signature: tx,
    },
    "confirmed"
  );

  const txDetails = await program.provider.connection.getTransaction(tx, {
    maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
    commitment: "confirmed",
  });

  const logs = txDetails?.meta?.logMessages || null;

  if (!logs) {
    console.log("No logs found");
  }

  assert(logs.includes("Program log: Instruction: SetFavorites"));
  assert(logs.includes("Program log: The number is: 23, the color is: red"));
});
```

Comment: thanks! I needed some extra bits but will put them in your answer.